# supervised classification

Tags: error, classification, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

I am having a problem in creating new signatures in Signature Editor in ERDAS 2014. Whenever I click on the icon (i.e., after selecting the aoi), it shows an error which says "unable to open associated image: Image association may be edited with Edit menu (Image Association...)". After I had set the associated image from the edit menu of the Signature Editor and tried to create new signature, it displayed "Viewer image does not match associated image for signature set. Image association may be edited with Edit menu (Image Association...)". PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: What sort of image are you working with? is it georeferenced?

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped me I was experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue however I cannot resolve it by changing the file names by using an underscore (_). Any ideas? Please help, I am really wasting so much time trying to resolve this without actually progressing with the actual assignment!

Comment: I have a problem. I can't put the same signature for a nother image for classification. please help me. i am working on sentinel 2 images. i want to make classification for these images in different months. and i can't put the same signature

Answer (score 2):

Check your folder name which contain your satellite imagery. Is it too long or is it contain spaces, like for example "D:\This is the folder name 123"? This kind of folder could raises problems in ERDAS.

I face the same problem, and resolve it just by move my image into the simple folder, such as "D:\Image". Just set this folder as your default data folder via File > Preferences; and try the same procedure for the AOI creation and adds it to signature editor.